# оverloading undefined dunder methods

Tags: python

```py
class T(): 
    ...


t = T()
t.__str__ = types.MethodType(lambda self: "qqqqqq", t)
print(t)  # default object.__repr__
```

Сould you explain to me the reason for this behavior. Maybe there is some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(t)` calls `t.__class__.__str__(t)`, not `t.__str__()`:

```
class T: 
    pass


t = T()

t.__str__ = lambda: "foo"
print(t)            # <__main__.T object at 0x000001FA84DA7D60>
print(t.__str__())  # foo

T.__str__ = lambda self: "foo"
print(t)            # foo
```

This is because special methods have special rules for how they're looked up:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary

In general, the solution is to define `__str__` in your actual class, and have its implementation be informed by class attributes as needed, rather than monkey-patching the entire method in individual instances:

```
class T: 
    def __str__(self):
        return "foo"


t = T()
print(t)  # foo
```